# Clearing saved passwords in browser

Tags: vb.net

Is there any possibility of clearing saved passwords using vb.net code from the browser (could be IE, Chrome or Mozzila).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Saved passwords is a user setting, and can't be affected by code in the browser.

Besides, the VB.NET code runs on the server, so it can't do anything at all to the browser.